# t-SQL - constraint on one column that has multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I am currently re structuring a poorly designed database, one of the things I want to do for integrity purposes is make a certain record unique dependent on a few variables.

The table I am using is Quotes, the column in question is the Quote number, what I need is for this to be unique to each Company and group, so for example `Quote001` should be unique unless there is a new company / group used.

So you could have `Quote001` with `company1` and `group1`, but then if a new quote is made with `company1` and `group1` the new quote number should be `Quote002`. However if `Company2` and `group1` make a quote it should be back to `Quote001`.

I am unsure as to how to achieve this most effectively, using constraints in the database.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: This is not an answer at all, but what's wrong with having totally unique quote number across all companies and groups? It would mean that even if you just have a quote number, you'd be able to pull up the record without needing the other information.

Comment: Agree with @Matthew, just have an incrementing `int` value and if you really need prepend the `Quote00x` to the start in any documents produced.

Comment: @Madhivanan I will get some examples together

Comment: @Matthew - The reason I want it sectioned is because the system in question is a CRM system which is used in various countries (which are determined by the groups) each country has separate access and permissions as do each account manager who only see specific companies in the system and they would only see their own quotes. Hence why I would like to have each with their own set of quote numbers.

Comment: @DavidWaldron Fair enough. I would still have an internal only PK for quick fetching and a computed value (as mentioned below) for the customer to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unique constraint.

```
            ALTER TABLE Quotes
            ADD CONSTRAINT ucQuote UNIQUE (QuoteNumber, Company, Group)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have an identity column on this table, I would use it to create a computed column for the qoute number. If you don't alrady have one, you can add it.

To do that, first you need to define a UDF that will do the calculation for you:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateQuoteNumber(@id int, @Company int, @Group int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Company = @Company
        AND [Group] = @Group
        AND id <= @id            
    )
END
GO
```

Then, you add the Quote number as a calculated column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
   ADD QuoteNumber as dbo.CalculateQuoteNumber(id, Company, [Group])
```

Now sql server will do the calculation for you, and you are safe since computed columns can't be inserted to or updated by the users.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/CFNOB12138)